# How is F2 a logical consequence of F1?

Tags: logic

[image]

I understand F2 is a logical consequence of F1 if, for all the cases where F1 is true, F2 is true as well.

Would appreciate help on how to go about questions like these.

Comment: That's exactly what formal logic is for! Symbolize both F1 and F2 and see what happens.

Comment: I think this depends a lot on which "common-sense" premises one accepts as being "purely logical". For example, it is tempting to accept as given that it is impossible for "the engineers repair the breach" and "the engineers do not have the necessary skills" to both be true at the same time -- but is that a mere matter of rewording the same claim or an extra-logical assumption that would need to be stated explicitly? (Ultimately how one chooses to answer that does not have a lot to do with mathematics, and the main purpose of exercises like this seems to be to confuse students).

Comment: Which of F1, F2 is true if a foreign engineer repairs the breach?

Comment: @HenningMakholm If they do repair the breach (by whatever methods, maybe Voodoo), then the skills they used were *sufficient* and hence skills they lack cannot be *necessary*.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Would you consider F2 to be true in a world where foreign engineers repair the breach _and_ water continues leaking? (I'm not sure myself, but I'm starting to doubt it makes sense to consider "unless" truth-functional).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, "continues leaking" seems to be incompatible with the *semantics* of "repaired". Then again, I guess that "expensively repaired and still broken" *does* happen in real life ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: That's just (part of) the point: is a conclusion that depends on the _semantics_ something the author of this exercise would call a "logical consequence"? Usually exercises like this are an attempt to drive home a point early in a logic textbook stating something like "logical consequence cares only about the _form_ of arguments; what the non-logical words in them _mean_ is immaterial". That leaves plenty of room to argue that the two claims are not _logically_ related, even though both of them can reasonably be said to be _true_ under the usual meaning of the words.

Comment: This is _on top of_ the uncertainty of which truth-functional meaning the author considers "unless" to have. Should "A unless B" mean $\neg A\to B$ or $\neg A \leftrightarrow B$ or perhaps even $B\to\neg A$?